# Lower bound inequality for $P(X<\mu-\sigma)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Is there a lower bound inequality for $P(X<\mu-\sigma)$, where $P$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ might be arbitrary but finite. For example by the [Cantelli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli's_inequality) we have an upper bound $P(X<\mu-\sigma)\le0.5$. Is there also a nontrivial lower bound inequality?

Comment: Nope, since for symmetric two-points distributions the probability is zero.

Comment: Do you know of any restriction to the distribution, such that such a lower bound exists?

Comment: You need to explain this more. I'm assuming $P$ is some type of probability? You say $P$ is arbitrary, but you need to clarify an arbitrary *what*.

Comment: Yes $P$ is a probability distribution.

Comment: I meant that $P$ can be any probability distribution. Bud as Did pointed out in general no such nontrivial lower bound exists. But what restrictions to the probability distribution can be made, such that such a lower bound inequality exists?